# Hook for customizing product image thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need a help on woo-commerce to override the cart product image thumbnail.
I am creating a plugin for customizing the product in the detail page and if we do "add to cart" it will be updated in the cart page with a customized thumbnail.

If any hook is available for overriding the image, please let me know.

Comment: Do you want same image as thumbnail or different for different products ?

Comment: In cart page only product thumbnail which I have customized should chage

Comment: Fixed some spelling and formatting. Removed irrelevant thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I've spent many hours searching for the answer also and even asked a Stackoverflow question ([WooCommerce: change product image permalink with filter/action hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32876133/woocommerce-change-product-image-permalink-with-filter-action-hook/32881776)) which now happens to be duplicate (could not find this question prior to submitting my own).*

## The answer:

The hook is `woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail`.
So in your `functions.php` add

```
function custom_new_product_image($a) {

    $class = 'attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image'; // Default cart thumbnail class.
    $src = [PATH_TO_YOUR_NEW_IMAGE];

    // Construct your img tag.
    $a = '<img';
    $a .= ' src="' . $src . '"';
    $a .= ' class="' . $class . '"';
    $a .= ' />';

    // Output.
    return $a;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', 'custom_new_product_image' );
```

and your thumbnails will be replaced (more processing needed if you want to change each thumbnail individually).

Answer (score 2):

To change thumbnail image size of WooCommerce cart page you need next steps:

1. In `function.php` create the size you need:

   ```
   if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
       add_image_size( 'custom-thumb', 100, 100, true ); // 100 wide and 100 high
   }
   ```
2. In `cart.php` which should be located in `your_theme\woocommerce\cart\cart.php` find

   ```
   $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image( 'custom-thumb' ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
   ```

Comment: Years of working with WooCommerce has taught me to edit the core templates as little as possible. It leads to more work further down the line. Use actions/filters

Answer (score 1):

Please review the WooCommerce cart templates in `woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php`.

There is a clear filter `woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail` for the product thumbnail in the cart.

```
$thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

Comment: Hello helgatheviking,thanks for your reply.I have seen this thing but I need to override my customized image with cart image.That means I have to do update option from my custom plugin.I don't want to customize I want to override.I need a hook to do this action.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. If you want to override the cart image, you use this hook. Please explain again if that is not what you are trying to do.

Comment: PS- I check stackoverflow in my own time and reply when/if I feel like it. Please only email me if you are ready to hire me.

Answer (score 1):

Change 'medium' for your required image size:

```
/**
 * Update cart product thumbnail
 */
function woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail_2912067($image, $cartItem, $cartItemKey)
{
    $id = ($cartItem['variation_id'] !== 0 ? $cartItem['variation_id'] : $cartItem['product_id']);
    return wp_get_attachment_image(get_post_thumbnail_id((int) $id), 'medium');
}
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail_2912067', 10, 3);
```

This results in your not having to update the core WooCommerce template files.