# WooCommerce: change product image permalink with filter/action hook

Tags: wordpress, image, url, hook, cart

I am looking for a filter/action hook (or any other way) to change image URL that is displayed on cart page as a thumbnail.
Example image: http://jamescollings.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/cart-donation-form.png

I found that it is retrieved via `$_product->get_image()` method, but I could not find anything similar to `$_product->set_image()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer:
The hook is `woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail`.
So in your `functions.php` add

```
function custom_new_product_image($a) {

    $class = 'attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image'; // Default cart thumbnail class.
    $src = [PATH_TO_YOUR_NEW_IMAGE];

    // Construct your img tag.
    $a = '<img';
    $a .= ' src="' . $src . '"';
    $a .= ' class="' . $class . '"';
    $a .= ' />';

    // Output.
    return $a;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', 'custom_new_product_image' );
```

and your thumbnails will be replaced (more processing needed if you want to change each thumbnail individually).

Comment: By default each thumbnail is a result from the product image. Changing each thumbnail needs to map to either order id or the product id. Btw did you work on different images for order items.