# How to add a cutom class to woocommerce cart thumbnail <img> tag throught a function?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

All the thumbnails in the cart are run through the following woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail filter:

```
$thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

**Any idea how to add a custom class to the `<img>` tag of the thumbnail through a function in the functions.php file of my child theme?**

Comment: I found a same question in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120671/hook-for-customizing-product-image-thumbnail, hope it can help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hook for customizing product image thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120671/hook-for-customizing-product-image-thumbnail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify class in attr argument of **get_image** function like this

```php
$thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(null, array('class' => 'my-custom-image-class')), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

**get_image** function accepts 3 arguments

```php
/**
     * Returns the main product image.
     *
     * @param  string $size (default: 'woocommerce_thumbnail').
     * @param  array  $attr Image attributes.
     * @param  bool   $placeholder True to return $placeholder if no image is found, or false to return an empty string.
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_image( $size = 'woocommerce_thumbnail', $attr = array(), $placeholder = true ) {
        $image = '';
        if ( $this->get_image_id() ) {
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image( $this->get_image_id(), $size, false, $attr );
        } elseif ( $this->get_parent_id() ) {
            $parent_product = wc_get_product( $this->get_parent_id() );
            if ( $parent_product ) {
                $image = $parent_product->get_image( $size, $attr, $placeholder );
            }
        }

        if ( ! $image && $placeholder ) {
            $image = wc_placeholder_img( $size, $attr );
        }

        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_get_image', $image, $this, $size, $attr, $placeholder, $image );
    }
```

In second $attr argument you can specify img tag attributes including class, if you defined your own custom thumbnail size, instead of passing null in first argument you can pass it, like this

```php
$thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image('my-custom-thumbnail-size', array('class' => 'my-custom-image-class')), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply find and replace the class

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', 'custom_class_woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail_filter', 10, 3 );

function custom_class_woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail_filter( $product_image, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
    $product_image = str_replace('class="', 'class="your-class ', $product_image);
    return $product_image;
}
```